# Creating vimrc breaks vim

Tags: debian, vim, tmux, colors

I'm currently logged into a server via ssh with `ssh -Y` and running a tmux session.

If I start vim and run `:colorscheme elflord` the color scheme is changed. (Although the colors are not exactly what I would expect although they are I think 256 color.

If I create a `~/.vimrc` file and put a single line

```
colorscheme elflord
```

in it then when I run vim it shows no color (just white text) and I cannot change the color with the `:colorscheme` command.

Comment: OK, but I think "breaks" is too strong of a word to use in that circumstance. I mean, you still have all the basic functionalities of Vim, correct?

Comment: I can use it to edit files, but no syntax highlighting doesn't work for example. I'm not sure what else I should test.

Comment: What happens if you issue `:syntax on` after opening Vim?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same `vim` before and after this experiment?  Are your results repeatable?

Comment: What's `$TERM` set to on each system? Read  `man tput`. Is the `elflord` colorscheme installed on the server?

Comment: @waltinator Please RTQ: "If I start vim and run :colorscheme elflord the color scheme is changed." So yes, elflord must be installed.

Comment: `$TERM -> xterm-256color`

Comment: @AndyDalton No I'm not, how can I check this?

Comment: @user3728501 `vim --version`

Answer (score 4):

In recent versions of Vim (starting with Vim 8, I believe), if the user has no personal `~/.vimrc` file, then Vim will execute the `defaults.vim` from its runtime directory instead, to load sane defaults.

The usual recommendation is that when you first create your `~/.vimrc` file, you should include a couple of lines at the top sourcing the `defaults.vim` file, in order to preserve the same settings you were getting from that file (which include enabling filetype detection and syntax highlighting.)

See [`:help defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim), which will tell you to start a new `~/.vimrc` file with the lines:

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
```

You can then add your `colorscheme elflord` configuration below these two lines. That should preserve the settings you get by default, but change the colorscheme you use at startup.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change color-scheme in `vimrc` you should also turn on `syntax`:

```
syntax on
colo elflord
```

Also check that the color-scheme is installed

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what is happening

- Creating the `~/.vimrc` file stops vim from reading the system wide vimrc file in `/etc/vim/vimrc`. (Or whereever it is on your system from standard install.)

I don't **know** if this is a bug. But I think it is. I don't know where to report bugs for vim. I will investigate.